# JSON AJAX call sending object as null to Java class

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I have the following getJSON method in my js file used as such:

```
$.getJSON('do/ajax-convertlocaldatetime', {
    timestamp : localdatetime,
```

The localdatetime variable is a *LocalDateTime* object. The ajax call calls a java class `ConvertLocalDateTime.java` which is supposed to the set `localdatetime` to a *LocalDateTime* variable named `timestamp`.

The issue is that the Java class is getting `null` for the `timestamp`. I confirmed the getters and setters are fine. I don't have an issue with getting `null` if I switch to using strings instead of *LocalDateTime* objects. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If your api works well (check by going on url yourweb.com/do/ajax-convertlocaldatetime), then try

```
var timestamp = "";
$.getJSON('do/ajax-convertlocaldatetime', function(data){
   timestamp = data; // or console.log(data) and check console in chromem,...
}
```